# How to hide bottom tab navigator (persistent_bottom_nav_bar) when the screen is not the main screens-Flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation, tabnavigator

I am currently using `persistent_bottom_nav_bar: ^4.0.2` package of flutter which showing 3 screens (A,B,C screens) in the bottom tab navigator. In the first screen I have a button that navigate user to another screen (D screen). The problem is the bottom tab navigator (persistent_bottom_nav_bar) is still showing in D screen, while the main screens are AB,C. Is there a way to hide persistent_bottom_nav_bar when the screen is not one of three main screen ?

Answer (score 0):

can you check  **persistent_bottom_nav_bar** in  **example** code.

```
onScreenHideButtonPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _hideNavBar = !_hideNavBar;
          });
        },
```

Comment: As I know ```onScreenHideButtonPressed``` is not a property of ```PersistentTabView```. ```onScreenHideButtonPressed``` is a parameter from a screen

Comment: In **PersistentTabView**  this property  `hideNavigationBar: _hideNavBar,`

Comment: to use that property I need to detect wether user is clicking the button from first screen or not (button that navigate user to D screen) and then notify PersistentTabView? but I don't know how to do that

Comment: you can use **bloc pattern**  or manage  **callback function** for  handle **_hideNavBar**

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a nice feature that comes with the plugin itself (check out the documentation on pub.dev here https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar, it's allowed you to navigate to a new screen without the navbar and when you pop back the navbar will show

try this

```
PersistentNavBarNavigator.sepushNewScreen();
```

there are some parameters that are required "screen & context" which is the screen you want to navigate to.

the parameter "withNavBar" it's a bool (optional) when you pass false the navbar will not show on the new screen!

you could try this after importing

```
PersistentNavBarNavigator.pushNewScreen(
  context,
  screen: newScreen(),
  withNavBar: false,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The navigation to other screens form the screens you are displaying Bottom Nav Bar should by done by using this function:

PersistentNavBarNavigator.pushNewScreen(
context,
screen: newScreen(),
withNavBar: false,
);

Use this instead of Navigator.push or other navigation functions.